# About the exact form of a gaussian kernel

Tags: notation

Traditionally we define a gaussian function at a point x (assuming mean to be 0) as follows

> $$g_{\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^{2}}} \exp\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)$$

In some sources however, the exact form is given as follows :

> $$g_{\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^{2}}\exp\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)$$

Why these two forms are used and where which one should be employed ?

For example, when I am working with images, a little difference produces great numerical variations which have an effect in terms of learning.

Comment: It may be a wild guess but I do know that the Gaussian kernel differs in the way you wrote it in the second formula for a $2-D$ system, where perhaps $x^{2}=|x|^{2}$

Comment: There are missing negation signs inside the $\exp$ function. Apparently, SE is stupid and won't let me do an edit which changes just 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

A gaussian function is any function of the form
$$
a\,e^{-b(x-c)^2}.
$$
A gaussian probability distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ corresponds to the first of your definitions.